# Google feed api behaviour

Tags: javascript, google-feed-api

I am eperimenting with google feed api. Basically I want a list of my feeds along with some information of the feed entries in order to process historical feeds normally not available on google reader. I am puzzled by one behaviour of google feed api which I document as comment in the code below. I am sure I don't get something since I am new to js.

This is the code with my question as comments:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8"  >


    google.load("feeds", "1");

   /* Here I define the list of my feeds */

   var feeds=['MYFEED1', 'MYFEED2', 'AND SO ON'];

    function initialize() {
      for (var j=0;j<feeds.length;j++) {
        var feed = new google.feeds.Feed(feeds[j]);
        feed.includeHistoricalEntries();
        feed.setNumEntries(100);

        feed.load(function(result) {
            if (!result.error) {
            var container = document.getElementById("out");
            var furl = result.feed.feedUrl;
            var flink = result.feed.link;
            for (var i = 0; i < result.feed.entries.length; i++) {  
                var entry = result.feed.entries[i];

                var div = document.createElement("div");

                /* HERE IS WHERE I DON'T GET IT. 
                                feeds[j] always just shows the last feed in the array. 
                                But furl always shows the correct feedUrl
                Though if I uncomment alert("NEXT") few lines below 
                                thus giving a short pause, feeds[j] correctly 
                                shows the same url as feedUrl. Why?  */
                div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(feeds[j]+" "
                             +furl+" "+flink+" "+ entry.link + " " + entry.title)); 
                container.appendChild(div);
          }
        }
      });
     //alert("NEXT");
    }
}

    google.setOnLoadCallback(initialize);

    </script>
  </head>
    <body><div id="out" ></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Also I would like to know if there's a way to set the values of the feeds array by querying a mysql database.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to me that feed.load() is an ajax call and you are passing a call back function to execute on returning from the request. Because ajax is async, the outer for loop continues to execute and as a result you are always seeing the last feed in the array.

I believe closures should help you in this situation.

Consider placing the whole block inside outer for loop in a separate function and use closure.
Something like this:

```
function initialize() {
for (var j = 0; j < feeds.length; j++) {
    (function(val) { //closure begin
        var j = val;
        var feed = new google.feeds.Feed(feeds[j]);
        feed.includeHistoricalEntries();
        feed.setNumEntries(100);

        feed.load(function(result) {
            if (!result.error) {
                var container = document.getElementById("out");
                var furl = result.feed.feedUrl;
                var flink = result.feed.link;
                for (var i = 0; i < result.feed.entries.length; i++) {
                    var entry = result.feed.entries[i];

                    var div = document.createElement("div");

                     /* HERE IS WHERE I DON'T GET IT. 
                            feeds[j] always just shows the last feed in the array. 
                            But furl always shows the correct feedUrl
            Though if I uncomment alert("NEXT") few lines below 
                            thus giving a short pause, feeds[j] correctly 
                            shows the same url as feedUrl. Why?  */
                    div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(feeds[j] + " " + furl + " "  + flink + " " + entry.link + " " + entry.title));
                    container.appendChild(div);
                }
            }
          }
        })(j); //Closure end
    });
    //alert("NEXT");
}​
```

Comment: thank you Harish, I tried what you suggested, adding the beginning and end of closure, but I don't get anything on the browser. Just blank.

Comment: @Gius - I am not familiar with google feed api but when I tried !result.error is always evaluating to false and so the code inside inside if block is never getting executed, hence the blank page.The error object has invalid url error (code 400).

Comment: but that error did not happen without the closure, thanks anyway. Not a big deal, I was just puzzled but I think that I understand the reason, as you said, is about being async